# How to get value of asset (coin) in USD using the python wrapper for Binance API?

Tags: python, cryptography, binance

Using the python-binance v1.0.15, how do I get the price of an asset in USD? For example getting the price of BTC in USD. (The reason I want this is to exploit price differences in the prices of stablecoins, such as the prices of USDT and USDC).

I was expecting to be able to do so using `price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol='BTCUSD')` but that gives me an `Invalid symbol` error.

Checking (what I believe to be) a list of all symbols, I only find trading pairs involving stablecoins (such as USDT), but no prices given in actual USD (fiat). As an example, here are all the symbols I find containing the strings `'USD'` and `'BTC'`:

['BTCUSDT', 'BTCTUSD', 'TUSDBTC', 'BTCUSDC', 'BTCUSDS', 'BTCBUSD', 'BTCUPUSDT', 'BTCDOWNUSDT', 'SUSDBTC', 'BTCSTBUSD', 'BTCSTUSDT', 'BTCUSDP'] (ref #)

produced using the following code

```
info = client.get_all_tickers()
symbols = []
for i in range(0, len(info)):
    symbol = info[i]['symbol']
    if 'BTC' in symbol and 'USD' in symbol:
        symbols.append(symbol)
```

I have a hunch that it might have something to do with using binance.com rather than binance.us. Unclear why this would be the case however.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** clarification - the underlying problem is that the trading tickers I'm looking for don't exist. I find no trading tickers that specify the price of a coin in USD, such as 'BTCUSD'. This is what the above list of symbols (ref#) is supposed to demonstrate.

Comment: instead of using `info[i]['symbol']` use `info[i]['price']` that should get you some conversion between the pairs  [python-binance documentation](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html#binance.client.Client.get_all_tickers)

Comment: Right - my problem is not how to find conversion between pairs. I can e.g. find the conversion between BTC and USDT or any other trading pair that exists as a valid ticker. The problem is that I don't find a way to get the prices in USD. since the tickers I'm looking for don't exist. There is e.g. no 'BTCUSD' that gets me the price of BTC in USD-fiat.

info[i]['price'] is only useful if the trade symbol I'm looking for (e.g. 'BTCUSD') exists. They don't - hence my problem.

Comment: Then actually you understand your problem. There is no price in USD because this markets dont exist. But they exist as BUSD, USDT and others.... pick one of them and use it.